# Fullcalendar, acces to data 'clientEvents'

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I initialize Fullcalendar from yii2 fullcalendar widget and trying to get event object by method 'clientEvents'. 
For example: $('.calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents').length return 0.

```
$body.on('mousedown', '.event-enabled', function(){

    var a = $('.calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents').length;
    console.log(a);
});
```

P.S.
[Fullcalendar clientEvents has zero length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995666/fullcalendar-clientevents-has-zero-length)
- this solution don't work

Comment: Or how to execute any fullcalendar method from external js?  $('.calendar').fullCalendar('unselect') works correct.

Comment: well simply remove the length ..